# Post image/video to facebook fan page as user

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

i am able to post image to page by using page access token . But it will post as page not as user logged in. If i use user access token it will post logged in user wall not to facebook fan page.
my goal is to post image/video to fan page as user not as page. the following code using to post to wall.

```
 var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
       {
            { "picture", video} ,
            {"message", "my Image"}                          
        };

        _fbClient.PostAsync("/{Page_id}/feed", parameters);
```

Please tell me how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for javascript? please note that the user have to like the page 1st before posting.

```
function PostToPage(){

    FB.login(function(response)
    {
        if (response.authResponse)
        {
             //Post to Wootube Page
             FB.api('/173724382762792/feed', 'post', { 
             message: lnk,
             link: lnk

             }, 
             function(response) {
               if (!response || response.error) {
                 //alert('You have to like http://www.facebook.com/WooTubes first!');

              } else {
                 //alert("Successfully Posted to WooTube Page!");

               }
             });

        }
        else
        {
            alert('Not logged in');
        }
    }, { scope : 'publish_stream' });


  }
```

Comment: POsting status/link is working fine for me. But Posting video and image is not working.

Comment: Hi Mahantesh, did you using facebook debugger to verify your link yet? have to make sure that your og property is configure correctly. Feel free to check out my og property using view source ->www.wootube.woolei.com  my user able to post to my page wall as a video using that script.